# Subscribing to windows phone UVC events, possible?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, background-audio

I have made a WP7.1 app that uses

```
BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance
```

to play() and stop(), and subscribes to events from

```
BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.PlayerState
```

to update the UI. I have a play button, and when I click that I update the UI to show a "buffering" animation, and when  BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.PlayerState changes to PlayState.Playing i show the "playing" animation instead. This works as expected. However when press play on the Universal Volume Control, the "Stopped" animation is shown until the PlayState.Playing event that updates the UI to "playing".

I thus need to detect when the play-button is pressed on the UVC (to show the "buffering" animation until the sound starts playing), but I cant find the events corresponding to that, any ideas?